# Seaborn PairGrid with matplotlib.pyplot.hist and hue

Tags: python, histogram, seaborn

Plotting histogram on a seaborn PairGrid with hue leads to stacking by default. Is there a way to avoid this ? (`stacked=False` is inefficient.)

I tried with `seaborn.distplot, kde=False` but the bars are too wide in my case and decreasing `rwidth` kind of shifts the bars away from the corresponding variable values (which does not happen with `plt.hist`).

EDIT code to illustrate so-called 'shifting away from the corresponding variable values' (actually plt.hist does it too but it is less obvious).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np    
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame()
for n in ['a', 'b']:
    tmp = pd.DataFrame({'name': [n] * 100,
                        'prior': [1, 10] * 50,
                        'post': [1, 10] * 50})
    df = df.append(tmp)

g = sns.PairGrid(df, hue='name', diag_sharey=False)
g.map_offdiag(sns.regplot, fit_reg=False, x_jitter=.1)
g.map_diag(plt.hist, rwidth=0.2, stacked=False)

g = sns.PairGrid(df, hue='name', diag_sharey=False)
g.map_offdiag(sns.regplot, fit_reg=False, x_jitter=.1)
g.map_diag(sns.distplot, kde=False, hist_kws={'rwidth':0.2})
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit what you mean by "kind of shifts the bars away from the corresponding variable values"? I think what you're seeing is that when you don't have a stacked hist, different bin positions will be chosen for each hue level. Another solution would be `g.map_diag(lambda *a, **kw: plt.hist(*a, **kw), rwidth=0.5, stacked=False)`, but I think that will have the same issue.

Comment: It indeed enables to use plt.hist without stack. As you point out plt.hist has the same issue though shifting is less obvious.

Comment: `sns.distplot` is just calling `plt.hist` to draw the histogram; the only difference is that `plt.hist` uses 10 bars by default whereas `sns.distplot` tries to guess a good number, and thus likely does not use 10. If you try with `bins=10` I assume you'll get identical results.